Why does the R-27 have reverse taper?

Pictured here is a R-27 missile. If you take a look at the forward fins, they have a reverse taper (meaning they have a higher chord as you extend span).
Aerodynamically speaking, this is the opposite of what you would want for efficiency (I think) so why are they configured this way?

The best information I found claimed that it was for a reduction in spanwise flow. (However I wasn't able to confirm if this info was accurate or not, and it was also using the XF-91 as an example)
My intuition also tells me this would increase the size/strength of the tip vortices, causing more issues, but perhaps also reducing the possibility of tip flow separation.

In terms of efficiency I think the reverse sweep is more efficient, but only slightly. R27's design seems to be based on mechanical structure, not aero efficiency. Remember this is a control surface, and the root is attached to a shaft on a single point. So the "fan-out" style is natural (imagine how you would design the skeleton inside the fins). Fixed delta wings are totally different, where the entire root chord is connected to the body, so the "taper out" style makes sense.

Interesting, what would make the reverse sweep more efficient? Larger tip vortices will induce more drag.


The pic above is from this link and seems to depict a modified R-27, with the fins in question now being middle fins. It can clearly be seen that they are mounted on swivelling axes, and are therefore active control fins, not passive stabilisation fins.
And for active control, we are more considered with an aerodynamic moment about the longitudinal missile axis, than we are with total drag. Therefore, more area away from the centre - creates more control.

And specifically, roll. The fins are to provide maximum rolling torque for the surface area.

It's not obvious to me why roll would matter, as it appears symmetrical about the roll axis.  I would guess that under the hood there's something like ground-imaging radar or something that cares about where it's pointing, but I'm only guessing.  A few words on the subject in the answer would be appreciated, by me at least, is all I'm saying.

@Roger Apparently the thing is able to spin in flight for one reason or other.

Further reading to Koyovis' answer: roll control by differential canard is very difficult

The fact that the front position of the rudders their deflection generates a bevel of air flow affecting the wings installed in the tail in such a way that a certain combination of angles of deflection of rudders, angles of attack and sliding, the phenomenon of reverse control on the roll - the moment from the aerodynamic forces on the wings acts in the direction opposite to the moment from the forces on the steering wheel, and exceeds it. Therefore, on almost all missiles made by the scheme of "duck", the rudders serve only to control the pitch and yaw, and on the channel of the roll are used either stabilizing ailerons or rollers, limiting the speed of rotation of the rocket on the roll.


Vimpel's designers managed to provide control of the rocket through all channels with differentiated deflection of the rudders, abandoning ailerons. For this purpose the K-27 used uniquely shaped butterfly wheels.


That quote doesn't make much sense. What's a bevel of air flow? And what's the scheme of duck? Butterfly wheels?

"duck" = "canard"?
